# SQL Server filtering on "as" label

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

What is this part of the SQL query called? Should I be able to filter on it?

[image: sql query]

Comment: That's a column alias, used to (re)define the name of the column in the resultset.  You'll need to filter using the statement that creates the column, in this situation the CASE statement.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can also filter using the cardinal index of the column, in this case (number of columns in d) + 6.  So if d has 7 columns,  `WHERE 13 = 'something'`

Answer (score 0):

When filter on a custom column or an alias; you need to filter using having clause
Try having Team='NOC' (line 23 of your code)